# Two pages with the same layout different text

Tags: php, html

I want to make two pages with the same layout only the text will be different on each page.

I don't want to copy the full page code. I know i can use PHP to include the layout, but the text needs to be different.

Answer (score 0):

You can use templating engine (Jamsheed anwser) or use php `include()`function.

---

**title.php**

`Here is my site title`

**content.php**

`My website content`

And then you can include title.php and content.php in your website

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xml:lang="fr" lang="fr">
        <head>
          <title><?php include('titre.php'); ?></title>
</head><body>
  <h1><?php include('content.php'); ?></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

As you mentioned, your text needs to be different, you can for example, use at the top of you page a `if` statement to check the get parameter of your page and include the right page 
(https://localhost/website**?article=home**)

I suggest you to take a look at [this post](http://inobscuro.com/tutorials/php-dynamic-includes-16/) which explains *PHP dynamic includesn* and *PHP dynamic content*.

Answer (score -2):

What you're looking for is a templating engine. [Here's a link](https://www.sitecrafting.com/top-5-php-template-engines/) to five of the best templating engines (opinion-based, of course) for PHP.

A templating agent allows you specify parts of a page that you want reused through multiple pages, specifying only content differences that modify a parent template. The link I posted above describes that some of the best templating agents for PHP include Blade, Mustache, Smarty, Twig, and Volt. Most of these are easy-to-use.